# Range of the function $f(x) = |x-3|+|x+5|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, absolute-value

As the title suggests, we have to find the range of  $f(x) = |x-3|+|x+5|$

I know how to find the range when we have a function in which only one modulus function is involved like $|x\pm a|$ or $k\pm |x\pm a|$, but I don't know how to solve this given question.

Being a newcomer to modulus functions, I asked my teacher this question. He suggested me to find the range by plotting graph of the function. I solved it using the method suggested by my teacher but I am wondering if there's any more feasiable method to find the range of this function.

Any hint would be enough, thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: There's no other way to be honest. Breaking the modulus and making a piece-wise function then plotting the graph or analyzing the expressions is the only way. An easy way to think is that since a modulus function is $\ge0$ and in this case you have +$\left|x+k\right|$ type, try to find if the minimum value 0 can be achieved or not, and the maximum value is infinity because all modulus are in addition.

Comment: Oh  thanks for your comment @Vega. Can you please explain what do you mean by **breaking the modulus and making a piece-wise function** ?

Comment: The function expresses the sum of the distances of $x$ from the points $3$ and $-5$, which must be at least $8$ since $3$ and $-5$ are eight units apart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the absolute value properties, we have
\begin{align*}
|x - 3| + |x + 5| = |3 - x| + |x + 5| \geq 3 - x + x + 5 = 8
\end{align*}

Comment: The property is $\left|x\right|+\left|y\right|\ge\left|x+y\right|$ if you are wondering.

Comment: May I know how did you get $|3-x| + |x+5| $ as the question is about $|x-3| +|x+5|$?

Comment: @ProThala Hint: |3|=|-3|=3, now can you understand?

Comment: So can I consider |x-3|=|3-x|? Is it necessary for both the graphs to be same?

Comment: Yes, they are the same.

Comment: @ProThala yes, use any graphing calculator and check that out.

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot both of you! :)

Comment: @ProThala In general, $|a -b| =  |-(b -a)| = |b -a|$.

Answer (score 1):

We can also do as follows:

Let,

$$y=|x-3|+|x+5|$$

Then, using the substitutions:

$$x+5=a,~x-3=b$$

We have,

$$\begin{align}&\begin{cases}y=|a|+|b|, \thinspace y≥0\\ a-b=8
\end{cases}\\\\
\implies &\begin{cases}a^2+b^2+2|ab|=y^2\\a^2+b^2-2ab=8^2\end{cases}\\\\
\implies &y^2-8^2=2\left(|ab|+ab\right)≥0\\\\
\implies &y≥8.\end{align}$$

---

Also we see that,

- If $x≥3$ or $x≤-5$ then $y≥8$.
- If $-5≤x≤3$, then $y=3-x+x+5=8$.

This means,  $y\in[8,+\infty)$.

[image]